# Expected value of function with normally distributed input

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, function

How can we calculate the expected value of a function $f$ with a normally distributed input? The function can vary.

Right now, I am sampling $n$ instances from the normal distribution, calculating $f(x)$ for $x \in n$, and averaging. I am sure that there must be a better way.

Comment: There are a couple of ways - a) the Delta method - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method  - which is valid for most functions $f$ b) the change of variable technique for deriving the distribution of functions of random variables - https://www.stat.washington.edu/~nehemyl/files/UW_MATH-STAT395_functions-random-variables.pdf

Comment: Note that the change of variable technique requires some attention as to whether the function is invertible, strictly increasing, etc.

Comment: It depends on the form in which $f$ is given you.  In some cases exact analytical solutions are possible; in others, you need numeric integration; in yet others--such as when $f$ is just a "black box"--the stochastic simulation you describe is one of the better ways.  (Ways motivated by experimental design considerations can improve on it, depending on assumptions you make about $f.$)

Comment: Thanks! In my case, $f$ is a utility function. Exact analytical solutions are not really possible and I am not sure about integration.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0, 1),$ the standard normal distribution.  Consider four functions $f(X):$

**Square.** Let $Y = f(X) = X^2.$ Then one can derive that
$Y \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 1),$ the [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with 1 degree of freedom, so that $E(Y) = 1.$
Starting with a sample, $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n,$ where $n$ is large, you could average values $Y_i = f(X_i) = X_i^2$ to get a good approximation of $E(Y) = 1.$  The approximation is better for larger $n.$ For $n = 10^6$ (a sample of a million), you get $E(Y)$ accurate to two or three places.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(100, 0, 1)
y = x^2;  mean(y)
[1] 1.252143

x = rnorm(10^6, 0, 1)
y = x^2;  mean(y)
[1] 0.9983859      # aprx E(Y) = 1
```

**Linear function.** Let $Y = 15X + 100.$ Here $Y \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15),$ so that $E(Y) = 100.$

```
set.seed(410)
x = rnorm(10^6, 0, 1)
y = 15*x + 100;  mean(y)
[1] 99.9901
```

Here are histograms of simulated values along with
appropriate density functions for the square and linear functions. (Making nice histograms for the exponential and reciprocal functions below is problematic.)

[image]

**Exponential function.** Let $Y = e^{X},$ so that $Y$ has a [lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with $E(Y) = e^{1/2} =  1.648721.$

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(100, 0, 1)
y = exp(x);  mean(y)
[1] 1.523783

x = rnorm(10^6, 0, 1)
y = exp(x);  mean(y)
[1] 1.652365
```

**Reciprocal.** Let $Y = 1/X$ so that $Y$ has a standard [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) for which $E(Y)$ does not exist. The difficulty is that there is a relatively high probability of dividing by a number very near $0.$ If you try the simulation method, you can get a wide variety of bogus answers for the
nonexistent $E(Y).$ This shows that the simulation method
has to be used with discretion.

```
set.seed(4321)
x = rnorm(10^6, 0, 1)
y = 1/x
summary(y)
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-258341.17      -1.48       0.27      -0.33       1.48  284488.81 

x = rnorm(10^6, 0, 1)
y = 1/x
summary(y)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-628911.1      -1.5      -0.2       0.0       1.5  288645.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! This does mean that there is no 'general' way of doing it, I think? That is unfortunate.

Comment: See comments and links beneath your question. Especially @whuber's. Some methods are widely applicable. I took some for granted to state actual dist'ns before simulating. Of course **nothing** will work if the mean doesn't exist (as in my 'reciprocal' example).